# Intercambiar pantalla completa en android studio con jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose

he estado intentando cambiar a modo pantalla completa en mi aplicación en android studio, Estoy usando jetpack compose y no tengo claro cómo cambiar al modo pantalla completa y viceversa. He buscado cómo lo podría hacer, pero no he dado.

Implementé el siguiente código

```
requestWindowFeature(
    if (epubReaderViewModel.state.isLoading) Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE 
    else 1
)

window.setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
)
```

Pero no funciona